# How to access session from generic handler

Tags: c#, asp.net

In ashx:
I'm putting data in list of entities & assinging it to session.

```
context.Session["objList"] = myEntityCollection;
```

I want to get this Session through response; in code behind.
How it is achieved?

```
context.Response.ContentType = ???
.....
context.Response.Write(context.Session["objList"]);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Serialize object to JSON, return serialized string with response and use `application/json` ContentType

Answer (score 2):

Hi if I understand you correctly. To access session data in an ashx file you need to implement the interface [IRequiresSessionState](http://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev10.query?appId=Dev10IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k%28SYSTEM.WEB.SESSIONSTATE.IREQUIRESSESSIONSTATE%29;k%28IREQUIRESSESSIONSTATE%29;k%28TargetFrameworkMoniker-%22.NETFRAMEWORK,VERSION=V4.0%22%29;k%28DevLang-CSHARP%29&rd=true)

```
public class ExampleHttpHandler : IHttpHandler, IRequiresSessionState
{
    public bool IsReusable
    {
        get
        {
            return false;
        }
    } 

    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {    
        context.Session["test"] = "test";
        context.Response.Write(context.Session["test"]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. But I'm already using that. The problem was that instead of getting object I was getting name of the object in code behind.