# How can i Get a Another Form Session Value in Java Script File Using ASP.Net?

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net, session

am having Sample.aspx and sample.js both are in different directory.

how can i get the Sample.aspx page session values in sample.js file ?

i cant get the value for the following types

```
    function session() {
        alert('<%=Session.getAttribute("hdn_CheckedData")%>');
        alert(document.getElementbyId("hdn_CheckedData").value);
        alert('<%=Session["CheckedData"]%>');
        alert('<%=Session("CheckedData")%>');
        alert('<%=Session["CheckedData"].ToString()%>');
        alert('<%=Session("CheckedData").ToString()%>');
    };
```

CheckedData - is the session

hdn_CheckedData - is the hiddenfield

i tried both of it.

is it possible then help me pls.....

Hiddenfiled, session, viewstate or anything............

Answer (score 2):

One simple solution is to declare the session variables just before the load of your javascript file and inside the aspx page. Eg on sample.aspx you have

```
<script>
var sessionCheckData = "<%=session["CheckedData"].ToString()%>";
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="sample.js"></script>
```

and on `sample.js` you have

```
  function session() {
        alert(sessionCheckData);
    };
```

Similar answer: [How to get asp.net client id at external javascript file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3845900/how-to-get-asp-net-client-id-at-external-javascript-file/3851247#3851247)

Comment: I don't think backticks are valid wrapper for JavaScript strings. [confirmed](http://jsfiddle.net/Vz47j/).

Comment: @ShadowWizard I Lost you. What I am try to say here is the inside the javascript can not render the session variable, so can he render it before.

Comment: While @ShadowWizard's solution will work, it makes the script dependent on a "global" variable that session.js does not if it will provided. I would recommend that rather than set the variable, why not simply pass it in as a parameter to the session() method?

Comment: @QuetiMporta you miss the point; JavaScript can't directly read session variables and you can't have `<%=` in .js file since it's not parsed by the server.

Comment: You are correct, however, you can still pass in the session variable by embedding it as the parameter to session()... <script type="text/javascript" src="sample.js"></script><script>
session("<%=session["CheckedData"].ToString()%>");
</script>

Answer (score 0):

You can save the session data to a hidden field on your page. After that you have direct access to that field in you js file.

Or you can declare a session  variable as **Aristos** has proposed. That would more straightforward actually.

Answer (score 0):

I would write a generic handler and use JSONP to pass any data to external Javascript.

Please take a look at [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12953397/how-to-access-session-from-generic-handler), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3702959/asp-net-generic-http-handler-ashx-supporting-jsonp) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2499567/how-to-make-a-json-call-to-a-url).

Since it is not cross domain, JSON should also work.

Answer (score 0):

You have to assign session values to hiddenfield

after that you can use that values